# What's a nice way to write a login required decorator for certain handlers in Tornado?

Tags: python, decorator, tornado

I have some web pages I want people to be logged in to see. I'm using Facebook connect for login, and running the site on a Tornado server.

Right now, I do this:

```
class Home(BaseHandler):
def get(self):
    if not self.current_user:
        self.redirect("/")
    else:
        context = dict(current_user=self.current_user, facebook_app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID)
        self.render("basic/home.html", **context)
```

Where BaseHandler is a modified handler that includes a method self.current_user that returns either a user object or None if there's no one logged in.

I was wondering what the best way is to rewrite this as a decorator which I could place on each handler I want to be locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't found the authenticated decorator

```
@tornado.web.authenticated
def get(self):
    ...
```

If you don't have a current_user it will redirect you to the `login_url` application setting.